# Routing elasticsearch document indexing issue

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, sharding

While creating an index of books with several authors but belonging only to a subset of 11 different publications, I intended to have 11 shards of the index on a single node.

Obviously the routing part of my mapping looked like,

```
"book":{
      "_routing":{
         "required":true,
         "path":"publication"
      },....
```

`publication` itself is a string which could be of 11 different types.

The `settings` part of my mapping looks like

```
body: {
    settings: {
       index: {
           number_of_shards: 11,
           number_of_replicas: 1
        }
     },....
```

The problem I'm facing is that docs of different `publication` have been indexed in the same `shard` while some shards are lying empty after I looked at the results of `books/_status` and`books/_segments` queries.

I looked into the `reroute` API but that obviously should be looked for other issues.

This unequal distribution of docs after specifying routing is tempting me to ditch `routing` altogether.

The version I've been using is 0.90.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routing doesnt gaurantee that all the items on a shard will have the same routing key, it will make sure that all the docs that share a routing key are all on the same shard.

[Here is a good ES post about it](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/customizing-your-document-routing/)

And a quote from the bottom:

> This shard almost certainly has documents other than those belonging
>   to user123. Routing ensures that documents of a particular routing
>   value all go to the same shard…but that doesn’t mean that other
>   documents aren’t routed to the shard too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.Should have found it myself.